# Proofs that Dirichlet's function is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Define $f: (0,1) \to (0,1)$ by

$f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{q}, & \text{if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$

The version of this proof I found from Spivak's Calculus is, for irrational $a$, say $a=m.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ is the decimal expansion of $a$, consider $[f(a+h)-f(a)]/h$ for $h$ rational, and also for $$h=-0.00\dots0a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\dots$$

Now I tried to prove this using the sequential criterion for limits.

Let $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be in reduced form, a sequence in $(0,1)$ converging to $a$. Then we can write $y_n=(\frac{1}{q_n}-0)/(\frac{p_n}{q_n}-a)=1/[q_n(\frac{p_n}{q_n}-a)]$. I first thought that since $(\frac{p_n}{q_n}-a)$ converges to $0$, $y_n$ would diverge to infinity, but then I realized that $q_n$ may also diverge to infinity, so I cannot guarantee this.

I'm wondering if there's another way using sequential criterion to prove this. Also what other solutions are there? I would greatly appreciate any solution.

Comment: Hint: $\left| a -\frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^2}$ for infinitely many integers $p,q$.

Comment: My previous answer was nonsense!  But I have posted a new one that seems to work.

Comment: Is it really **Dirichlet's function ?**...I know it as Riemann function or Thomae's function..

Answer (score 1):

Fix an irrational $x\in(0,1)$.  Suppose $f'(x)$ exists; then $f'(x)=0$.  For each prime $q$, pick $r_q$ to be a multiple of $1/q$ satisfying $|x-r_q|\leq 1/q$. Then $|f(x)-f(r_q)|/|x-r_q|\geq 1$.  So $|f'(x)|\geq 1$,a contradiction.

Comment: How do we know that for each prime $q$ there is $r_q$, which is a multiple of $1/q$ satisfying $|x-r_q|\lt 1/q$?

Comment: Choose $r_q=\max\{n/q : n \in \mathbb{N}, n/q <x\}$.

Comment: Can we really choose $r_q$ for any prime? I think you need the additional restriction that $1/q\lt x$. So I'm thinking that, to make every point clear, there exists $\epsilon=1$, for which given any $\delta \gt 0$, we can choose a prime $q$ such that $1/q$ is less than both $x$ and $\delta$, then by your reasoning, we've a contradiction. Second point, is the prime assumption necessary? I think that the same idea works without necessarily choosing primes.

Comment: We can easily ensure that $q$ is large enough.  After all, we can start the sequence $\{r_q\}$ at any prime we want.  (Nevertheless, the assumption in the answer holds for any prime.  For example, if $x=1/4$ and $q=3$, we can just pick $r_q=1/3$.)

Comment: Also, I threw in the prime assumption since the definition of $f$ requires $p/q$ to be reduced.